# Trigger function for multiple elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have multiple div elements with similar buttons that have the same class name, I am trying to trigger the event handlers respective of the button I click. I have tried the "each" jquery function but it only triggers the first element. I tried using document on click too. i added stopPropagation and preventDefault too.

```
<div id="overview-comment-container" class="social-comment-container">
        <ul class="comments-list">
            <li class="posted-video-comment">
                <div class="comment-body-divider"></div>
                <div class="comment-list-divider" align="center" width="90%"></div>
                <div class="comment-user-details">
                    <span class="delete-comment"><img id="erase-img" title="Delete comment" src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/484/484662.svg"></span>
                    <span class="edit-comment"><img class="edit-img" title="Edit comment" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61456.svg"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="commentinfo-block-wrapper">
                    <div id="distinct-user-comment" contenteditable="false">Salute</div>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-buttons" style="display: none;">
                    <button id="update-button" class="social-update-button"> Update </button>
                    <button id="cancel-button" class="social-cancel-button"> Cancel </button>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-body-divider"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="posted-video-comment">
                <div class="comment-body-divider"></div>
                <div class="comment-list-divider" align="center" width="90%"></div>
                <div class="comment-user-details">
                    <span class="delete-comment"><img id="erase-img" title="Delete comment" src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/484/484662.svg"></span>
                    <span class="edit-comment"><img class="edit-img" title="Edit comment" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61456.svg"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-block-wrapper">
                    <div id="distinct-user-comment" 
contenteditable="false">Hello</div>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-buttons" style="display: none;">
                    <button id="update-button" class="social-update-button"> Update </button>
                    <button id="cancel-button" class="social-cancel-button"> Cancel </button>
                </div>
                <div class="comment-body-divider"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

$( '.edit-img' ).each( function() {
        $(this).click( function(e) {

            e.stopPropagation();

            var editComment = $( '#distinct-user-comment' );
            var editCommentText = editComment.text();
            $( '.delete-comment' ).css( "visibility", "hidden" );
            $( '.edit-comment' ).css( "visibility", "hidden" );

            editComment.html( '<textarea class="editPostedComment" placeholder="'+ editCommentText + '"style="width: 60%;">'
                                + editCommentText +
                              '</textarea>' );

            $( '.editPostedComment' ).one('focus', function() {
                $( this ).text( editCommentText );
            });

            $('.comment-buttons' ).show();
        });
    });

$( '#cancel-button' ).click( function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();

            var onEditComment = $( '.editPostedComment' );

            onEditComment.replaceWith('<div id="distinct-user-comment" contenteditable="false">' + onEditComment.attr('placeholder') + '</div>');
            $( '.comment-buttons' ).hide();
            $( '.delete-comment' ).css( "visibility", "visible" );
            $( '.edit-comment' ).css( "visibility", "visible" );
        });
```

Comment: You have multiple items with same id= 'distinct-user-comment' this is wrong and this will result in always the first element with this id to be selected. You do no need an .each() loop to handle all elements with same class.

Comment: @NawedKhan using ia class instead of an id doesn't that solve this too

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid not. You have to be more specific about what is not working. Which button.. cancel or edit-image is not working. What error you are getting.

Comment: @NawedKhan There are no errors, its just every event handler button i click only triggers action on the first element like you said. I put it on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/or2sxmjc/

Answer (score 1):

The reason only first comment is handled is having same ID for multiple elements. ID is meant to be unique and only first of the element with same IDs are selected, always.

Secondly, you have to establish a context that identifies a comment and then refer everything inside that context. In your case it is the 'li' tag with class 'posted-video-comment'.

We will use JQuery's closest() method to find the parent 'li' and then use .find() method inside the 'li' every time we want to refer to an element, by class, for that comment.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="overview-comment-container" class="social-comment-container" style="border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);">
  <ul class="comments-list">
    <li class="posted-video-comment">
      <div class="comment-body-divider"></div>
      <div class="comment-list-divider" align="center" width="90%"></div>
      <div class="comment-user-details">
        <span class="distinct-user-name">Tope Babz</span>
        <span class="distinct-timestamp">5 secs ago</span>
        <span class="delete-comment"><img id="erase-img" title="Delete comment" src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/484/484662.svg"></span>
        <span class="edit-comment"><img class="edit-img" title="Edit comment" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61456.svg"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="commentinfo-block-wrapper">
        <div class="distinct-user-comment" contenteditable="false">Salute</div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-buttons" style="display: none;">
        <button class="social-update-button"> Update </button>
        <button class="social-cancel-button"> Cancel </button>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-body-divider"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="posted-video-comment">
      <div class="comment-body-divider"></div>
      <div class="comment-list-divider" align="center" width="90%"></div>
      <div class="comment-user-details">
        <span class="distinct-user-name">Sergio</span>
        <span class="distinct-timestamp">15 secs ago</span>
        <span class="delete-comment"><img id="erase-img" title="Delete comment" src="https://www.flaticon.com/premium-icon/icons/svg/484/484662.svg"></span>
        <span class="edit-comment"><img class="edit-img" title="Edit comment" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/61/61456.svg"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="commentinfo-block-wrapper">
        <div class="distinct-user-comment" contenteditable="false">Hello</div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-buttons" style="display: none;">
        <button class="social-update-button"> Update </button>
        <button class="social-cancel-button"> Cancel </button>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-body-divider"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript: 
    $('.edit-img').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();

```
  var $li = $(this).closest('.posted-video-comment');
  var editComment = $li.find('.distinct-user-comment');
  var editCommentText = editComment.text();
  $li.find('.delete-comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
  $li.find('.edit-comment').css("visibility", "hidden");

  editComment.html('<textarea class="editPostedComment" placeholder="' + editCommentText + '"style="width: 60%;">' +
    editCommentText +
    '</textarea>');

  $li.find('.editPostedComment').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).text(editCommentText);
  });

  $li.find('.comment-buttons').show();
});

$('.social-cancel-button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var $li = $(this).closest('.posted-video-comment');
  var onEditComment = $li.find('.editPostedComment');

  onEditComment.replaceWith('<div id="distinct-user-comment" contenteditable="false">' + onEditComment.attr('placeholder') + '</div>');
  $li.find('.comment-buttons').hide();
  $li.find('.delete-comment').css("visibility", "visible");
  $li.find('.edit-comment').css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

And here is the [working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/fj59b3zg/)